# Dozens of gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-autologin] processes

Tags: gdm, auto-login

I have a non-server Ubuntu installation which I mainly use as a headless server. I don't remember what was the first version installed (there were several major upgrades) but right now I'm using the following:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

And I have dozens processes which look like this (from htop):

```
2167800 root       20   0  162M  7536  6756 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 ├─ gdm-autologin]
2167803 root       20   0  162M  7536  6756 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  ├─ gdm-autologin]
2167802 root       20   0  162M  7536  6756 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  └─ gdm-autologin]
```

And if I try to count them:

```
ps aux | grep gdm-autologin | wc -l
237
```

I suspect that it is not normal and if it is indeed not, what can I do about it?
I don't know when they started to appear in masses because I started noticing those only after my interaction with `apt` (mostly `updgrade`) started giving me the following:

> Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: The maximum number
> of active connections for UID 0 has been reached

and

> Error connecting:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum
> number of active connections for UID

Can these be connected?

---

**UPD**: Found another weird thing that I think is connected to all of this. Ran `journalctl _UID=1000` and got 4116108 lines of logs since Feb 11. And it mainly contains the same Xorg log repeating over and over again: [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/BGb9p97A)

Answer (score 1):

So I just came across this problem myself, as my machine was running at 100% all the time.

I find this a very dirty hack, but using the information in [Gnome's "Configure automatic login" help](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en), I found the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and turned off the autologin process by commenting out these lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=username
```

I then killed all the process, and my CPU has returned to normal.

The issue has not came back after restarting, and everything seems to be working as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using Fedora PAM autentIcation to AD domain
autologin may not work for domain users.
There are some solutions which can help:

For autologin to gdm environment (using gdm-autologin) you need to put in
/etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
ad_gpo_map_deny = -gdm-autologin
ad_gpo_map_permit = +gdm-autologin
```

check it by:

```
 journalctl -xeu sssd.service
```

to prevent some GPO warnings good idea is set:

```
ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = True
```